# Add object routedValue in Confirmation dialog of a Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, confirmation, ajax.beginform

What I want is to add an object routed value when the user submits the form (ajax.beginform)

Depending on what the user chooses in the ConfirmDone function, i want to add an integer (SaveOption)

But i don't really know how to do it.

The confirmdone function is called but that's it, my controller action is'nt called. I probably need to return something?

Some Code: the start of the form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial", "Functiebeschrijving", new     AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Functiebeschrijving", OnBegin = "return ConfirmDone()", OnSuccess = "handleSuccess" }, new {@id = frmID}))
{
```

The confirmdone function

```
function ConfirmDone() {
    if (confirm("This form saves default as Concept, would you like to save it as completed? 1 = Completed, 2 = Concept")) {
        //option 1: save as completed
        $('#frmID').attr("SaveOption", 1);                        
    }
    else {
        //Option 2: save as concept
    }
}
```

The start of my controller action

```
//
// POST: /FunctieBeschrijving/CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial(NieuweFunctiebeschrijvingViewModel nfvm, int SaveOption)
{
```

When i don't use the confirm function, everything is posted as it should be!

Comment: What kind of element is having the id `frmID`?

Comment: The form (ajax.beginform)

Comment: `<form saveOption="1">` attribute doesn't get posted as part of the form data, you better use `<input type="hidden" id="saveOption" value="1" />` then in your `ConfirmDone` function `$('#saveOption').val(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addDataToUrl(url, name, value){
    var sep = url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
    return url + sep + name + '=' + value;   
}

function ConfirmDone() {
    var form = document.getElementById('frmID');
    if (confirm("This form saves default as Concept, would you like to save it as completed? 1 = Completed, 2 = Concept")) {
        //option 1: save as completed
        form.setAttribute('action', 
        addDataToUrl(form.getAttribute('action'), 'SaveOption', '1'));                   
    }
    else {
        // Option 2: save as concept
    }
}
```

Comment: the string SaveOption is null in the controller action, but the url good is  I think, this came out google chrome's developer tools: /Functiebeschrijving/CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial?Length=19&SaveOption=1

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck You are using wrong overload of Ajax.BeginForm, write:

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateFunctiebeschrijvingPartial", "Functiebeschrijving", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Functiebeschrijving", OnBegin = "return ConfirmDone()", OnSuccess = "handleSuccess" }, new {@id = frmID}))`

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck change name of the parameter, name it "sopt" for example instead of "SaveOption"

Comment: for some reason the sopt parameter works, but I have to submit the form twice to execute the POST. How can I execute the POST action the first time?

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck sopt parameter worked because you have used SaveOption in other place too, maybe you have used it in `NieuweFunctiebeschrijvingViewModel` class? twice? that's maybe because you are not returning anything from ConfirmDone method, try returning `true` at the end of the method

Comment: return true does not help

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck That's not related to question. I can't do everything for you :)

Comment: That function addDataToUrl(url, name, value), how can I modify that so there's a check if the url already has a routedvalue, if it does, it needs to be removed

Comment: You can remove query and add it again:

`function removeQuery(url){
    var index = url.indexOf('?');
    return index === -1 ? url : url.substring(0, index);
}`